# Are Keychron keyboards compatible with Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, ubuntu-drivers

I have a question about Keychron keyboards: are they compatible with the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Operating System?

As far as I know, its compatibility is limited to MAC and Windows.

I appreciate any information on this.

Comment: You can always boot to a Live USB and test it out.

Comment: @Terrance True, except if someone does not already have the keyboard and is interested in buying one, so they cannot test it.  In any case, most computer peripherals don't mention Linux compatibility, but chances are that they work on Linux, having at least basic functionality.

Comment: Most keyboards will work fine with Linux.  The compatibility might be with software that controls functionalities of the keyboards, i.e. light colors, volume control, function keys, etc.  There are a lot of git sites that may contain Linux software for keyboards.  Searching through the interwebs turned up one like https://gist.github.com/andrebrait/961cefe730f4a2c41f57911e6195e444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all compatible with Linux (doesn't matter distro) so you should be fine. It's better if the board you choose from them is VIA compatible.

Remember Winkey == Super == Mac CMD

With VIA you map the layout as you see fit. If you don't do a low profile switch, there are tons of keycap sets that have icon mods or straight-up Super key keys. :D

tl;dr You'll be fine with 99% of the choices on the site. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Keychron works in Ubuntu 22. I have a Keychron K7 working well with Ubuntu 22 by Bluetooth. No specific setup is required.

Till now, any problem I faced was resolved thanks to @andrebait and his excellent notes in https://gist.github.com/andrebrait/961cefe730f4a2c41f57911e6195e444